# php action code not working with javascript confirmAction()

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, web

I have this php file which suppose to have a button to do some checkout functionally action by calling a JavaScript built-in function to do it

```
<a href="index.php" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" > onclick="confirmAction()" <i class="icon-edit">Check out</a>
```

I used **confirmAction()** like this

```
<script>
                        // The function below will start the confirmation dialog
                        function confirmAction() {
                            let confirmAction = confirm("Dose the maintenance finished yet?");
                            
                            if (confirmAction) {
                                
                                alert("Action Done")
                        
                            } 
                            else {
                                alert("Action canceled");
                            }
                        }
                    </script>
```

if the user pressed ok I want to do php code
which should do post action

```
controller.php?action=checkout&code=<?php echo $result->CONFIRMATIONCODE; ?>
```

but I wasn't successful in making it work inside the **TRUE** case in the javascript function

basically I tried to run the php code without the  tag but I failed

any suggestion ?
Thanks

Comment: I see no reference to `controller.php` anywhere in the code.  Are you looking to redirect the user to that page?  Make an AJAX request to that page?  Something else?  It's not clear to me what specifically you're expecting this code to do that it isn't doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use code like below, if you want to redirect in cancel event then add code like: window.location.href = 'http://www.google.com';

Form:

```
    <form method="POST" action="controller.php" id="myForm">
  <input type="hidden" name="action" value="checkout"> 
  <input type="hidden" name="code" value="put code here"> 
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" onclick="return confirmAction()" ><i class="icon-edit">Check out</i></a>
</form>
```

script:

```
function confirmAction() {
                        let confirmAction = confirm("Dose the maintenance finished yet?");
                        
                        if (confirmAction) {
                            
                            alert("Action Done");
                            document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
                        } 
                        else {
                            alert("Action canceled");
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
```